# Function to wrap Hibernate Transactions

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, session, transactions

This is not a problem, exactly, more an open question.  I was tired of finding this pattern in many places in this body of code I inherited, so I figured I would make put it all in a function.  I can't have been the first to invent this, but I couldn't find it already implemented anywhere.  Here is the function, which I put in a utility class.

```
public static <R> R transactionWrap(Function<Session, ? extends R> function) {
    Transaction transaction = null;
    try (Session session = HibernateUtilities.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        R result = function.apply(session);

        transaction.commit();
        return result;
    } catch (Throwable th) {
        if (transaction != null) {
            transaction.rollback();
        }
        throw th;
    }
}
```

And here is an example of usage.  It's rare that the usages of this don't actually have a return value, so I just return true in that case.  (But this was one nice, small sample that I had handy.  It's been anonymized to Thing from the entity type I actually am using.)

```
public static void deleteThing(int id, AuditIdentity auditIdentity) {
    transactionWrap(session -> {
        Thing thing = ThingsDbManager.get(session, id);
        if (thing == null) {
            throw new NotFoundException("Thing not found.");
        }
        ThingsDbManager.deleteThing(session, thing, auditIdentity);
        return true;
    });
}
```

Are there any problems I'm not anticipating?

I tried searching for something like this, but it isn't obvious what to search on.  Googling the entire text is unhelpful.  I also tried asking ChatGPT, and it mentioned some libraries that we aren't already using, so I didn't bother to track them down.  The Apache dbUtils was the only one that sounded particularly promising, but I didn't want to pull it in to the project just for this.